# How do I import an object from main.py (in the root directory), into a module contained in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-module, pythonpath

So, this is the project structure:

```
<root directory>
- app 
- - name
- - - module1
- - - module2
- - - module3
- - - - tests.py 
- test_db.py
```

test_db.py contains an object called `client` which I need in all the tests.py files in different modules.

I could simply move test_db.file inside the app directory but test_db.py needs to import `app` from main.py which is again in the root directory and will cause the same issue again.

In every tests.py I need something like:

```
from ....test_db import client
```

but it just gets:

> from ....test_db import client
>
> ```
> E ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
> ```

So, I just can't figure out importing an object/package from the root directory.

P.S: I know one simple solution would be to change the directory structure a little, but It's a large project and changing the structure would be a LOT of work. So, ideally I need some way to add the root directory to the path inside every tests.py file. Something like this:

app/name/module3/tests.py:

```
import sys

#sys.path.something.. I am not really familiar with how to use this

from ....test_db import client #this should import client from test_db in root instead of throwing error

def test_create_todo():
    pass
```

Comment: why not add an `__init__.py` file to the main directory, add the path to pythonpath and then just use `from test_db import`  in the sub-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a relative import without hacking around with `sys.path` or custom loaders/finders, you need:

- the top-most directory you import relative to to contain an `__init__.py`
- to specify said directory as a package in the path to your `__main__` module (i.e. `python -m root.stuff.main`)

In short, this means you could add a directory `project` to contain the `test_db.py` and `app`, add an `__init__.py`, and call your program with `python -m project.app.stuff.main`.

If this doesn't work for you (you mention you don't want to change the project structure) you do have other options.

You could install each as its own package (`app`, and `tests`). Create a `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`/`pyproject.toml`, put `test_db.py` in a package `tests`, and pip install them as editable packages `pip install -e .`. This will allow you to import either without relative imports (just `import app`, and `import tests.test_db`, regardless of file). This is personally the route I would go, and recommend doing.

Otherwise, if you're just looking for a quick fix, there exists one more easy + hacky solution. You could add the path for `test_db.py` to `sys.path` (every path in this list is explored for the target module when importing), so you could import `test_db` from anywhere. Again, this is very hacky, and I don't recommend it beyond quick sanity checks or extremely urgent patches.